# Retrieve generated ID using MyBatis Annotation Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am trying to learn MyBatis. How to do I get the auto-generated ID after I have inserted a statement using the `@Insert`Annotation.

Example of my code:

```
@Insert("INSERT INTO user(name, mobile, password) VALUES(#{name}, #{mobile}, #{password})")
@SelectKey(statement = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()", keyProperty = "id", before = false, resultType = Long.class)
Long insertUser(User user);
```

I want to get the generated id as the return from the insert method.

Answer (score 8):

`@SelectKey` is for legacy drivers.
For recent drivers, you should use `useGeneratedKeys`.
We have an [FAQ entry](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/FAQ#how-can-i-retrieve-the-value-of-an-auto-generated-key) explaining how to do it with XML mapper.
With annotation, it would look as follows.

```java
@Insert("INSERT INTO user(name, mobile, password) VALUES(#{name}, #{mobile}, #{password})")
@Options(useGeneratedKeys = true, keyProperty = "id")
int insertUser(User user);
```

Note that `@Insert` method returns the number of updated rows, not the generated key.
The generated key is assigned to the property of the parameter specified by `keyProperty` i.e. `User.id` in your case.

For some databases, you might need to specify `keyColumn` as well.
If it didn't work, please add versions of DB, driver and MyBatis to the question.

Comment: I have tried 
@Options(useGeneratedKeys = true, keyProperty = "user.id", keyColumn = "user.id"), which works. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 2):

```
 @Select("insert into security.users (name,email,password) values(#{user.name}, #{user.email}, #{user.password}) returning id")
 @Result(column = "id")
```

this worked me. but i try a many time  with @INSERT annotation not worked;

Comment: maybe you are reading the result of the insert function, but it does not return the id, but the number of inserted columns.
and at the same time, the model is updated automatically.
i.e., you do not need to do 
`Integer id = mapper.insert User(user); user.setId(id);`
just do the insert and omit the result, your model will already contain the correct id